# Apply the same function over all the elements in a folder

Tags: r, datetime, missing-data

I have a folder in the computer containing 184.000 different .RData, all are small dataframes representing an investor transactions in a specific asset.
the dataframes represents the combinations between 4.000 investors and 6.000 assets.
I have holes in the data, in practice I want to use the complete() function to complete each dataframe by adding the missing rows based on the column datetime.

I want R to apply the complete() function on all the elements of the folder of my pc, but I have no idea how.
I came up with the basic idea which are the following lines of code but I don't know how to tell R to apply it to the entire folder.

```
path_to_read \<- "dev/test-data/investors-rdata-assetbased/" # path to single .RData

path_to_save \<- "dev/test-data/investors-completedatetime/"

file_names \<- list.files(path_to_read, ".RData")

df$datetime \<- as.Date(df$datetime, format =  "%Y-%m-%d")
df \<-   complete(datetime = seq(min(datetime), max(datetime), by = "1 day"), fill = list(number = 0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `map()` function from `purrr` R package.

**Note:**
I'm assuming that each RData contains a `data.frame` called **df** with at least two columns called *datetime* and *number*.

First, define you "complete date" function as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

complete_date <- function(df) {
  min_date <- min(df$datetime)
  max_date <- max(df$datetime)
  datetime = seq(min_date, max_date, by = "1 day")
  
  table <- tibble(datetime = datetime, number = 0)
  
  table %>% inner_join(df, by = "datetime")
}
```

We gonna apply this function over each RData using map:

```
file_names %>% 
  map(function(file_name) {
    load(file_name) # Load RData first
    complete_date(df) # Apply the function
  })
```

This will create a list of all the complete data.frames, which you can use to write as RData with `save()`.

Comment: nice idea but unluckily my files have names wich are made of "Investor.Asset" so I though about something like you said but I have this problem, I don't know how to overcome the obstacle of these different names